# Creating GUI for matrix vector multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, tkinter

I am writing a script to perform matrix vector multiplication with GUI using Tkinter of Python. I am new to `TKinter` and I am trying to learn. I have written the following code for this purpose. The `generate_data` function gets a a number (e.g. `m`) and creates a `mxm`matrix. In GUI, the user should enter an integer for matrix and an integer for vector and press compute so the `matvec` function performs the calculation.

I think I have not understood properly some parts but I would need some explanations at this stage. My main challenge is to insert the `generate_data` function in a way that can be used in GUI to create a random matrix. At the end of code, I have copied the error. Thanks in advance.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import dotprod

base = Tk()
resultStr = StringVar()
resultStr.set("Enter Matrix1 and Matrix2")

matrixLabel = Label(text = "Enter the size of the matrix:")
matrixLabel.pack()
matrixBox = Entry()
matrixBox.pack()

vectorLabel = Label(text = "Enter the size of the vector:")
vectorLabel.pack()
vectorBox = Entry()
vectorBox.pack()

def generate_data(m):
    test_data = []
    for i in range(m):
        test_data.append([])
        for j in range(m):
            test_data[i].append(random())        
    return test_data

def matvec():
    m = int(generate_data((matrixBox.get())))
    v = [2] * len_m
    vec = [0] * len(m)
    for i in range(len(m)):
        vec[i] = dotprod.dotprod(m[i], v)
    resultStr.set("Matrix vector product is " + str(vec))
    return vec  

Computebutton = Button(text = "Compute", command = matvec)
Computebutton.pack()
base.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in matvec
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in generate_data
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - `range(m)` in `generate_data` expects `m` to be an `int`, but `matrixBox.get()` has supplied a `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from an `Entry` field is a string type, but range takes an integer type.
Therefore, when you call `generate_data(matrixBox.get())`, you pass a string to `generate_data`.

You can solve this by calling `generate_data(int(matrixBox.get()))` or by adding `m = int(m)` as the first line of your `generate_data` function.